# Integration testing native SQL query when using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, orm, integration-testing

I use Hibernate and widely adopted Hibernate Query Language to define queries in my DAOs.

Anyway sometimes HQL isn't capable of performing specific task compared to native SQL query.

For example the following Postgres expression is not "convertible" to HQL:

```
my_date > current_date - interval '10 year'
```

This means that in some case I'm writing native queries. Considering that I'm using another database for integration testing (http://hsqldb.org/) which doesn't reflect the syntax of the Postgres expression above. This results in test exception during DAO methods using such native query.

How do you handle such cases? I can just think of following scenarios:

- Never use native query and try to build everything in HQL *(possible?)*
- Don't test methods which use such queries *(unhappy)*
- Use same database both for production and development *(performance problem)*

Other, more interesting solution? Thanks

Comment: You're using another database for _unit testing_? I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of unit testing. You shouldn't be hitting a database at all. When you start to hit a database, you're now using _integration testing_. Unit tests are intended to cover one particular *unit* of code (generally a class), and should mock any and all external dependencies that the class may have.

Comment: @ColinMorelli so how do you test DAOs in unit tests? How do you *mock away* the database?

Comment: Maybe one solution would be to extend some hibernate/jpa classes (for instance the EntityManager) to alter the SQL before sending it to HSQLDB.

Comment: you are right, it's more integration tests, I've just fixed the question accordingly

Comment: You don't "mock the database." You mock your Hibernate object which ultimately talks to your database. Your unit test should not test whether or not objects actually make it to the database or not. Just that the expected code is executed. Your integration tests will make sure that your systems work together.

Comment: @Wizche I think you're missing the point. If you separate unit and integration testing, then your question is answered. Your unit tests don't talk to your database. Your integration tests should *absolutely* talk to a replica of your production environment. So, you simply talk to a development PostgreSQL database. Then your problem is avoided entirely. Testing against a different environment  with different systems somewhat defeats the purpose of testing. You should always aim to emulate production.

Comment: Thanks Colin, I'm just trying to check that my queries actually returns the correct data by using a test database (where I now the records in it and I can check the query are returning the right results). So you're saying I should use an exact copy of my production server?

Comment: @Wizche No, you should use an exact copy of your production _schema_ (without the data). Your integration tests should insert any test data that needs to be inserted, and then subsequently make your DAO call to ensure that the proper data is returned. In either case, you should be querying against Postgres, since that's what you have in production

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the purpose of integration testing is to test against (very) similar environment to production, hence IMO you should use the same database engine. For unit testing however using HSQLDB is fine. In which case unfortunately the classes that has dependency to Postgres couldn't be unit tested, you have to wait until integration testing to detect bugs.

On a side note however the result of the Postgres SQL you mentioned can be achieved by performing the date arithmetic on Java.

```
Calendar currentDateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
currentDateCal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10);
Date currentDate = currentDateCal.getTime(); // bind this currentDate object into your HQL parameter
```

Comment: You shouldn't be talking to a database at all in a unit test, it should be testing _a specific portion of your code_ with no external dependencies.

Comment: Thanks gerry, although many people are completely against using a different database for "whatever" test, I think u are right, If I have dependency on the database syntax, I can either use the same database or adapt the query.